# ClassCastException: <![CDATA[java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Object;]]>

Tags: jsf, classcastexception, state-saving

When I'm trying to click on the submit button, initially method is calling and executing but when I'm trying to click the same submit button for the second time I'm facing the below issue in response:

Below is the code:

```html
<h:commandButton class="nxt_btn clone_nxt_btn" value="Submit" action="#{cloneDAO.launchWorkflow()}" id="submit">
</h:commandButton>
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Object;
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreSystemEventListeners(UIComponentBase.java:1864)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1565)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:380)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1652)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1663)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:367)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:138)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:577)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:142)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:301)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:301)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:192)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: Is the object you initially passed to jsf (GET) the same type with the object you passed to jsf from launchWorkflow() (POST??)

Comment: Please do not use [java] tag as long as the problem is not demonstrable using a plain vanilla Java application class with a `main()` method.

Comment: You'll need to add a breakpoint on ClassCastException and debug a little bit in order to find out which exact UIComponent is biten here. This component somewhat illegally has its' state stored as a HashMap instead of an Object array (`Object[]`). As we don't see the relevant code we can't really help further.

Comment: launchWorkFlow() method return type is void and I have written only single log statement. Eventhough I'm facing this issue. When ever I'm running for the first time after restarting the services, it is working fine. But second time method is not calling and I'm not getting any exception in logs as well. But while debugging I'm facing the below issue in browser network response. <partial-response><error><error-name>class java.lang.ClassCastException</error-name><error-message><![CDATA[java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to [[Ljava.lang.Object;]]></error-message></error></partial-response>

Comment: I have replaced the UI code as below:   <h:commandButton value="submit" styleClass="nxt_btn clone_nxt_btn"  id="submit">
  <f:ajax listener="#{cloneDAO.launchWorkflow()}"/>
   </h:commandButton>